# cl /out => option 'o' has been deprecated => zero-byte ut file

Tags: visual-studio, cl

```
cl t2.c /out:full.exe
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.25.28611 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
t2.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.25.28611.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:t2.exe
/out:ut:full.exe
t2.obj
```

File `ut` is a zero-byte file.

What is going on? Where `ut` name comes from? Why `ut:full.exe`, but in reality there is `ut` (zero-byte file)?

Comment: /out is not a compile option, /o is old and no longer documented.  In effect it created ut.exe with an [alternate data stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_(ADS)) named "full".  Use /link to pass options to the linker.

Comment: Thanks! Ended up with `cl t2.c /link /out:full.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant:

> Option /o is old and no longer documented. Use /link to pass options to the linker.

Solution: `cl t2.c /link /out:full.exe`.

Comment: `/OUT` is sometimes problematic. It can be confused with `/O` series of options leading to D8016 error (`/O` vs some other command incompatible)